# How do methods defined on constructor prototypes have access to instance members in the constructor in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am learning about prototypes in Javascript and the prototype chain, but I am confused on the following issue. Lets say I have constructor below:

```
function Circle() {
    this.radius = 1;
}

let c1 = new Circle();

Circle.prototype.toString = function() {
    console.log('The radius is: ' + this.radius);
}

c1.toString(); // "The radius is: 1"
```

In the above example, `c1` and `Circle` both reference the same object in memory for their prototype. The `toString` function is defined on the prototype, not in the constructor. So, when I call `toString` on `c1`, javascript engine should look at `c1` first, then look at the prototype object, which contains the `toString` function. It is looking "up" the prototype chain.

My question is, why does `this.radius` work? How does the toString function, which is defined on the prototype, know about instance members defined in the constructor? That is like looking "down" the prototype chain, from the prototype object to the actual instance object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is simple. The `this` will always refer to it's caller object.

In this case the `toString` method is called on  `c1` instance so inside the `toString` the `this` will refer to the `c1` and it will find the `radius` property in that.

Comment: brilliant, i completely forgot about that, thanks. will accept answer when time limit is up.